# Is the Picard number bounded by $b_2$ in positive characteristic?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, shimura-varieties

We know that for a smooth projective variety $X$ over an algebraically closed field of characteristic 0 (for example $k=\mathbb{C}$),  $\rho(X)\leq b_2(X)$. What about in positive characteristic? Is it true that $\rho(X)\leq b_2(X)$, where $b_2(X)$ is the second Betti number of some kind of good cohomology ($\ell$-adic, deRham, etc).

P.S. I only know that Igusa proved that $\rho(X)\leq b_2(X)$ for algebraic surfaces.

Comment: A minor correction: in char 0, $\rho(X)\le b_2(X)$, not necessarily strictly less.

Comment: Homological and numerical equivalence for divisors coincide, so $NS(X)\otimes \mathbb{Q}_\ell$ injects into $H^2(X_{et},\mathbb{Q}_\ell)$. So yes, $\rho(X)\le  b_2(X)$ in positive character*istic*.

Comment: You don't  need the coincidence of homological and numerical equivalence for divisors, in fact the result holds for cycles in any dimension: the group of codimension $p$ cycles 
mod. numerical equivalence is a quotient of the group of  codimension $p$ cycles 
mod. homological equivalence, which tensored by $\Bbb{Q}_{\ell}$ injects into $H^{2p}_{ét}(X,\Bbb{Q}_{\ell})$.